# Cannot close Firefox window after Selenium WebDriver test (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, junit, annotations, webdriver

I know there are a few other similar questions on here, but I read through them and was unable to solve my issue. I also am not entirely fluent in JUNIT annotations and the like, so that is kind of confusing me as well. Here is what I have, and I just want the firefox window to close after a successful (or unsuccessful) test.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestWorkGaps extends TestCase {
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    driver = (WebDriver) new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://dev.XXX.com";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    success = core.TestCore.checkMain(driver);
    if (!success) {
        fail("Main page did not load correctly.");
    }
//various other tasks
success = core.LoginLogout.logout(driver);
    if (!success) {
        fail("Not able to logout.");
    }
}

@After
public void closeWindow()
{
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance, you guys are the best. I can provide my pom.xml if it is relevant.

Comment: What exactly is it doing and what should it be doing? At first glance the code looks fine to me.

Comment: I would like it to close the firefox window after completion of the test. At present, the window just stays open.

Comment: The code you have given looks fine.  In your `checkMain` or `logout` functions, are you calling `new FirefoxDriver()` ever?

Comment: yes - as Nathan said, this looks just fine.  I assume so, but you *are* running as jUnit right?  (also, @SamFrench, just followed you back on github `:)` [ddavison](https://github.com/ddavison))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing old and new JUnit; this is why it is not working. You have two possible ways of fixing this:

1. The old way: remove the annotations and rename `closeWindow()` to `tearDown()`. This will override the corresponding function in `TestCase`.
2. The new way: don't extend `TestCase`. Then the annotations will be used and the `closeWindow()` method will be called.

Your `setUp()` function already overrides the corresponding function in `TestCase` which is why that part worked. The `closeWindow()` however was unknown to `TestCase` and it seems JUnit uses a different runner if `TestCase` is extended.

Comment: Hey, I left the annotations and renamed closeWindow() to tearDown() and it works. Thanks.